# Not able to navigate to another page on button in jsf portlet

Tags: jsf-2, liferay-6

I am trying to develop a jsf portlet(primefaces 3.2)

I have created a jsf portlet in which i am displaying a datatable.Inside my datable there is one button.

Now when i will click on that button a jsp page should open. its not working actually.

I am trying to achieve it using this way.

```
<div style="text-align:right">
                        <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="1000" height="840">
                            <h:outputLink
                             value="./next.jsp">
                                <p:commandButton value="Add" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="margin:3px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"/>
                            </h:outputLink>
                        </p:lightBox>
                    </div>
```

My current portletViewMode.xhtml(portlet display page) and next.jsp are present inside portlet(in xhtml folder).

Its a jsf view(portletViewMode.xhtml) which creates when you create a jsf-portlet ,and in that view I have displayed a datatable inside there is a button.

When I 'll click on that button I should be able to navigate to a jsp page which acts as a light box.. So if I close I should be able to see my previous jsf view.

So  I am trying to navigate from jsf view  to another jsp page on action of a button(which is a jsf component) .

what should I need to do for that?
Have any one tried navigate from jsf view to any other page.?

Comment: Primefaces and JSP don't work togeter. So you might encounter problems if you use Primefaces components on next.jsp. In general: Why do you mix JSP and facelets? Use the one _or_ the other, preferable facelets.

Comment: Yes, instead of jsp page we can take xhtml file also. I have tried in that way also.In next.jsp or next.xhtml I was just trying to display simply 'hello world. But my basic problem is I am not able to navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `p:lightBox` in a wrong way.

Regarding the example on the Primefaces homepage you should use the `p:lightBox` with `iframe="true"` in order to display page content.

Wrapping an `h:commandButton` with an `h:outputLink` is not the most elegant solution. You could use a simple `h:button` but it will also work with a `h:commandButton`:

```
<p:lightBox iframe="true">
    <h:outputLink value="page2.xhtml"  >  
        <h:commandButton action="#" value="Next page" />  
    </h:outputLink>  
</p:lightBox>
```

Note that the content of the iFrame needs to go in the `value` attribute of `h:outputLink`.

Furthermore, JSP and Primefaces won't work. Use facelets only.